# Cannot convert method group '###' to non-delegate type UnityEngine.Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to simulate a gravity affect in unity for objects near an object with this script attached; to do this I try and add a force to the objects towards itself. However I am running into an issue with `other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce()` I get the following error:

> Cannot convert method group 'forceCalculation' to non-delegate type 'UnityEngine.Vector3'. Consider using parentheses to invoke the method.

```
public class planetaryForce : MonoBehaviour {
    public float gravityPower;
    public GameObject planetaryCore;
    public float range;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if (distance (other.gameObject) < range) {
            other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce (forceCalculation(other.gameObject), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    public float distance(GameObject other){
        float distance = Vector3.Distance (other.transform.position, transform.position);
        return distance;
    }

    public Vector3 direction(GameObject other){
        Vector3 direction = transform.position - other.gameObject.transform.position;
        return direction;
    }

    public float multiplier(GameObject other){
        float multiplier = range - distance(other);
        return multiplier;
    }

    public Vector3 forceCalculation(GameObject other){
        forceCalculation = direction(other) * multiplier(other);
        return forceCalculation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Vector3 forceCalculation(GameObject other) {
    forceCalculation = direction(other) * multiplier(other);
    return forceCalculation;
}
```

The first line declares a method with the name `forceCalculation`.

The second line then attempts to assign a Vector3 to a previously registered name `forceCalculation` (which is a method).

Fix this by *declaring a variable:*

```
public Vector3 forceCalculation(GameObject other) {
    Vector3 forceCalculation = direction(other) * multiplier(other);
    return forceCalculation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `forceCalculation()` you are returning a the `forceCalculation()` method, what you should do instead:

```
...
public Vector3 forceCalculation(GameObject other){
    Vector3 calculation = direction(other) * multiplier(other);
    return calculation;
}
```

Comment: Within seconds of each other!